# fileman on ckeditor 4 with absolute path for images

Tags: ckeditor, roxy-fileman

I installed fileman (roxyfileman.com) on ckeditor 4, when I upload image i get relative path

/maillist/maillist/admin/js/ckeditor/fileman/Uploads/roxy-fileman-logo.gif

which absolute path should I put on conf.json
"FILES_ROOT": "",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY": "",

to obtain

http:// www. mydomain.com/maillist/maillist/admin/js/ckeditor/fileman/Uploads/roxy-fileman-logo.gif

thanks

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, I just added an absolute URL inine RETRUN_URL_PREFIX

Hope this helps!

```js
{
"FILES_ROOT":          "",
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   "https://www.strategic-options.com",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "",
"THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH":   "140",
"THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT":  "120",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_WIDTH": "100",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_HEIGHT":"100",
"MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH":     "1000",
"MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT":    "1000",
"INTEGRATION":         "ckeditor",
"DIRLIST":             "php/dirtree.php",
"CREATEDIR":           "php/createdir.php",
"DELETEDIR":           "php/deletedir.php",
"MOVEDIR":             "php/movedir.php",
"COPYDIR":             "php/copydir.php",
"RENAMEDIR":           "php/renamedir.php",
"FILESLIST":           "php/fileslist.php",
"UPLOAD":              "php/upload.php",
"DOWNLOAD":            "php/download.php",
"DOWNLOADDIR":         "php/downloaddir.php",
"DELETEFILE":          "php/deletefile.php",
"MOVEFILE":            "php/movefile.php",
"COPYFILE":            "php/copyfile.php",
"RENAMEFILE":          "php/renamefile.php",
"GENERATETHUMB":       "php/thumb.php",
"DEFAULTVIEW":         "list",
"FORBIDDEN_UPLOADS":   "zip js jsp jsb mhtml mht xhtml xht php phtml php3 php4 php5 phps shtml jhtml pl sh py cgi exe application gadget hta cpl msc jar vb jse ws wsf wsc wsh ps1 ps2 psc1 psc2 msh msh1 msh2 inf reg scf msp scr dll msi vbs bat com pif cmd vxd cpl htpasswd htaccess",
"ALLOWED_UPLOADS":     "",
"FILEPERMISSIONS":     "0644",
"DIRPERMISSIONS":      "0755",
"LANG":                "auto",
"DATEFORMAT":          "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
"OPEN_LAST_DIR":       "yes"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recent version of roxy fileman added a parameter for this: RETURN_URL_PREFIX which can be set in the conf.json file. 
It works well but require you to hardcode the full URL in conf.json

However, if you need something more flexible,  for example if you deal with several environement, you can modify the way RETURN_URL_PREFIX parameter works by making it a boolean flag:

- set it to "1" in conf.json
- modify main.js, lines 700-701 and 801-802 with:

  ```
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.RETURN_URL_PREFIX){
      var prefix = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname;
  ```

instead of:

```
if(RoxyFilemanConf.RETURN_URL_PREFIX){
var prefix = RoxyFilemanConf.RETURN_URL_PREFIX;
```

**edited:** here is how your conf.json should look like, note the RETURN_URL_PREFIX value:

```
{
"FILES_ROOT":          "",
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   "1",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "image_browser_url",
"THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH":   "140",
"THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT":  "120",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_WIDTH": "100",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_HEIGHT":"100",
"MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH":     "1000",
"MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT":    "1000",
"INTEGRATION":         "ckeditor",
"DIRLIST":             "php/dirtree.php",
"CREATEDIR":           "php/createdir.php",
"DELETEDIR":           "php/deletedir.php",
"MOVEDIR":             "php/movedir.php",
"COPYDIR":             "php/copydir.php",
"RENAMEDIR":           "php/renamedir.php",
"FILESLIST":           "php/fileslist.php",
"UPLOAD":              "php/upload.php",
"DOWNLOAD":            "php/download.php",
"DOWNLOADDIR":         "php/downloaddir.php",
"DELETEFILE":          "php/deletefile.php",
"MOVEFILE":            "php/movefile.php",
"COPYFILE":            "php/copyfile.php",
"RENAMEFILE":          "php/renamefile.php",
"GENERATETHUMB":       "php/thumb.php",
"DEFAULTVIEW":         "thumb",
"FORBIDDEN_UPLOADS":   "zip js jsp jsb mhtml mht xhtml xht php phtml php3     php4 php5 phps shtml jhtml pl sh py cgi exe application gadget hta cpl msc jar vb jse ws wsf wsc wsh ps1 ps2 psc1 psc2 msh msh1 msh2 inf reg scf msp scr dll msi vbs bat com pif cmd vxd cpl htpasswd htaccess",
"ALLOWED_UPLOADS":     "",
"FILEPERMISSIONS":     "0644",
"DIRPERMISSIONS":      "0755",
"LANG":                "auto",
"DATEFORMAT":          "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
"OPEN_LAST_DIR":       "yes"
}
```

Comment: i do this, everything goes true except the 1 added to src.

Comment: @Peymanabdollahy : could you please be more specific about the problem ? For now, I just do not understand your situation/expectation.

Comment: I do what you say, and it work's except the 1 in the RETURN_URL_PREFIX : "1" added to begining of the absolute path.